# Crear Id en un DataGridView

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2015, linq

Hola tengo un DGV  en la cual por intermedio de un boton quiero crear su codigo correlativo cuando precione el boton

```
private void btnNuevoClasificacion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClasificacionTalla ct = new ClasificacionTalla();

        int Id = (from item in listCT select (item.ClasificacionTallaId)).Max();
        int resultado = Id + 1;


        listCT.Add(ct);
        dgvClasificacion.DataSource = null;
        dgvClasificacion.DataSource = listCT;
    }
```

Me sale error en la linea del int Id la secuencia no contiene elementos

Comment: en el codigo veo que usas listCT.Add(ct); pero donde cargas inicialmente los items de listCT ? no puedes obtener un Max si la lista no tiene items, debes asegurarte que la hayas cargado previamente

Comment: En mi lista listCT no tengo nada exepto las propiedades de la lista. ¿Debo cargar items de una tabla vacia?

Comment: sino hay item quizas debas definir el resultado = 0, pero la verdad no entiendo el codigo donde usa "resultado" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sino hay items en la lista deberias validarlo antes de aplicar el Max()

```
private void btnNuevoClasificacion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int resultado = 1;

    if(listCT.Count > 0){
        int Id = (from item in listCT select (item.ClasificacionTallaId)).Max();
        resultado = Id + 1;
    }

    ClasificacionTalla ct = new ClasificacionTalla();
    ct.ClasificacionTallaId = resultado;
    listCT.Add(ct);

    dgvClasificacion.DataSource = null;
    dgvClasificacion.DataSource = listCT;
}
```